# VueJS 2 properties not being passed down in production build

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm struggling with getting properties to work in the production build of my Vue app. Everything appears to work fine in development, but when the app is compiled it doesn't. Take this navigation component I'm using for example:

**navigation.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import template from './navigation.html';

export default Vue.extend({
  props: ['activePage'],
  template,
  methods: {
    setActivePage: function() {
      // Set activeEl to ref (see template) that corresponds to activePage parameter
      var activeEl = this.$refs[this.activePage];
      if (activeEl) {
        activeEl.className += ' active';
      }
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.setActivePage();
  }
});
```

**navigation.html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navigation">
        <div class="navigation__bar">
            <router-link to="/"><img class="navigation__brand" src="placeholder" /></router-link>

            <ul class="navigation__links">
                <li class="navigation__link" ref="a"><router-link to="/">a</router-link></li>
                <li class="navigation__link" ref="b"><router-link to="/b">b</router-link></li>
                <li class="navigation__link" ref="c"><router-link to="/c">c</router-link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

This is how I use this component:
`<navigation activePage="a"></navigation>`

So, this component takes an `activePage` property, checks the template if there is a ref that corresponds to the `activePage` value, and if that is true, it adds the `active` class to the ref element. It works with the development build, but in production it results in this:

`<div class="container" activepage="cases">`

Am I doing something wrong here? My project is based on this template, if that matters: https://github.com/villeristi/vue.js-starter-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case

You have to use kebab case when binding camelCased props. You will need to use

```
<navigation active-page="a"></navigation>
```